# Julia: how to mimic some "typedef/using" we use in C++ (and without perfs penalty)?

Tags: optimization, types, julia

Basically, I want to provide some type information in a `struct A` that will be used later to define the return type of the `foo_1` function.

Here is the Julia code I have so far:

```
struct A
    type::DataType
end

foo_1(a::A)::a.type = 2018
```

Usage example:

```
julia> a=A(Float64)
julia> foo_1(a)
2018.0
```

-> This work as expected: 2018 is converted into `a.type` type, here a `Float64`

However, my problem/interrogation come from that fact that, when compared with the function `foo_2` that do basically the same thing without using `x.type`

```
foo_2(a::A)::Float64 = 2018
```

there is an **important** difference in the generated code:

```
julia> @code_native foo_2(a)
    .text
Filename: REPL[4]
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movabsq $139943184603960, %rax  # imm = 0x7F470FCE9B38
Source line: 1
    movsd   (%rax), %xmm0           # xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

-> This is OK

However for `foo_1(a::A)::a.type` function:

```
julia> @code_native foo_1(a)
    .text
Filename: REPL[3]
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    pushq   %r15
    pushq   %r14
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $56, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, %r14
    movq    %fs:0, %r15
    addq    $-10888, %r15           # imm = 0xD578
    leaq    -48(%rbp), %rdi
    xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, -48(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -32(%rbp)
    movq    $8, -72(%rbp)
    movq    (%r15), %rax
    movq    %rax, -64(%rbp)
    leaq    -72(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, (%r15)
    movq    $0, -56(%rbp)
Source line: 1
    movq    (%r14), %rax
    movabsq $139943153507008, %rcx  # imm = 0x7F470DF41AC0
    leaq    634701288(%rcx), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, -48(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
    movq    %rcx, -32(%rbp)
    movabsq $jl_apply_generic, %rax
    movl    $3, %esi
    callq   *%rax
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    movq    %rbx, -56(%rbp)
    movq    (%r14), %rsi
    movabsq $jl_typeassert, %rax
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    callq   *%rax
    movq    -64(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, (%r15)
    movq    %rbx, %rax
    addq    $56, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    popq    %r15
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

-> I am surprised that Julia JIT is not able to generate an optimized function. IMHO it has all the required information at the call site `foo_1(a)` to do so.

--> I fear that the difference in generated code is so big that I will get bad performance if I use the approach with `a.type`.

**So my questions are:**

- 1/ is there a better Julia way to define type information (I am thinking of `typedef` C++ equivalent)
- 2/ how to explain the generated code difference between foo_1(a) and foo_2(a)

  -> My explanation so far: I think that like foo_1 is not a parametric function Julia generates only **one** instance of the function and hence it is obliged to **dynamically** resolves the type (even if struct A is **immutable**). Am I right?

---

**Note:** I could have written

```
struct B{T}
end

foo_3{T}(b::B{T})::T  = 2018
```

That works (in the sense that native code of `foo_3` is the same as `foo_2`), however this is an awkward solution to define several types:

```
struct B{T1,T2,T3,...}
end
```

C++ equivalent would be, without "parasite" template parameters:

```
struct B {
    using T1 = ...;
    using T2 = ...;
    using T3 = ...;
    ...
};
```

Comment: The difference betwee foo_1 and foo_2 is that in foo_2 the compiler knows what the endgame is at compile time, whereas in  foo_1, it has to figure it out from the value of the argument. It can only know the value of the argument at run time. You can check https://github.com/blackrock/NamedTuples.jl for a package using the "awkward" parameterized type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is simply that Julia doesn't know what type `A.type` is beyond the fact that it's just some `DataType`.  You can use a parametric type to provide this information:

```
julia> struct A{T}
           typ::Type{T}
       end
       foo_1(a::A)::a.typ = 2018
foo_1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo_1(A(Float64))
2018.0

julia> @code_native foo_1(A(Float64))
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
; Function foo_1 {
; Location: REPL[9]:5
    movabsq $4572864984, %rax       ## imm = 0x1109061D8
    movsd   (%rax), %xmm0           ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    retq
    nop
;}
```

Comment: Thanks, I do agree with your answer. However, I am still a little bit disappointed: see the "struct B{T} end" section, end of my post. If I have several types, I have to define A{T1,T2, etc.}. If I want to add a type I will have to change A{} signature (by adding a type).

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Julia does its specialization based upon the types of the objects it receives within each function.  In your first example, Julia _only_ knows that it has an object of type `A`, and `A.typ` could be _any_ `DataType`.  So it must dynamically look it up.  It works just fine; just not as fast as you'd like.  The solution is to hoist that `typ` information up to the outer structure in a parameter.  You're right that this is effectively the same as your last example. I misunderstood your complaint there.